# Getting zsh: segmentation fault in arm64 visual studio code

Tags: c

> This code is giving errors after this
> Enter the number of students:  2  Enter the 1 Student Name :  erabq
> zsh: segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int m, n;

void display(char n2[m][n], int x2[], char c1[], int p);

void display(char n2[m][n], int x2[2], char c1[], int p)
{
  for (int j = 0; n2[p][j] != '\0'; j++)
  {
    printf("Student Name :  %s \n", n2[p][j]);
  }

  printf("Student Roll No : %d \n", x2[p]);
  printf("Student Class : %s \n ", c1[p]);
}


int main()
{
  char n[50][50], c[5], n1[50];
  int y, x[8], x1;
  int p1 = 0;
  int a = 0;

  printf("Enter the number of students: \n");
  scanf("%d", &y);

  for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
  {
    printf("Enter the %d Student Name : \n", i + 1);

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
      scanf("%s", n[i][j]);
    }

    printf("Enter the Student Class : \n");
    scanf("%s", c[i]);
    printf("Enter the Student Roll No : \n");
    scanf("%d", &x[i]);
  }

  printf("Enter the Student Name and Roll Number :\n");
  scanf("%s %d", n1, &x1);

  for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
  {
    if (x[i] == x1)
    {    
      for (int j = 0; n[i][j] != '\0'; j++)
      {
        if (n[i][j] == n1[j])
        {
          p1 = i;
          a = 0;
        }
        else
        {
          a = 1;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (a == 0)
  {
    display(n, x, c, p1);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("No Such Entry!!");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your compiler should have warned you about not passing a pointer for the argument to `scanf`. In *two* places actually.

Comment: And that whole loop `for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Your code would be much easier to understand (including for you) if you'd use meaningful variable names instead of n, c, x2, c1, p etc.

Comment: And none of the "student" arrays match each other in size. You have 50 elements for student names, only one really for the class, and eight for the roll number.

Comment: Furthermore, even if the search loop doesn't find a suitable student, you will still display student information for the first student (index `0`).

Comment: Can you please resend me the right one which doesn’t have any errors

Comment: For j<4 i was just trying to check if the other for loop logic is actually right

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)